# Sort List with two parameters but in different lines of code

Tags: list, linq, sorting

I have a method which sorts a List of Clients.

There are two parameters I want to sort by. 
I am well aware of the

```
List.OrderBy(x => x. [...]).ThenBy...
```

Method but my situation is a bit different:

```
switch(mySortType)
{
     case SortType.mostVisits:
         clients = clients.OrderBy(x => x. and so on...)
     break;
     More cases with different sortTypes
}
```

And after that I would like to sort after a Boolean parameter, but only if the settings tell the method to do so via another bool.
Ist there a way to say something like

```
clients = clients.OrderBy(Current).ThenBy(x => x.param).ToList()?
```

I could of course have an if() in every case

```
case SortType.MostVisits:
  if(settingsTellsMeToDoSo)
     clients = clients.OrderBy(x=>x.numberOfVisits).ThenBy(x => x.param).ToList();
  else clients = clients.OrderBy(x => x.numberOfVisits).ToList();
```

and then use the simple ThenBy Method but I thaught that there has to be an easier way to do it.

I hope you got my question right. I am not sure whether or not I was able to explain well enough...

regards,
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the problem is to decide which lambda to put into `OrderBy` (as opposed to the rest of the lambdas, which go into `ThenBy`) you can use a little trick, and put all your lambdas (or no lambdas if no sorting is to be performed) into `ThenBy`. Since `ThenBy` is an extension method on `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, you need a way to make a regular enumerable into an ordered enumerable without disturbing the original order.

You can make an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` from your `IEnumerable<T>` (or `IOrderedQueryable<T>` from `IQueryable<T>`, depending on your situation) by applying a dummy sort on a constant, like this:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<Client> orderdClients = list.OrderBy(c => 1);
```

Now you can apply `ThenBy` repeatedly as needed. This approach is similar in nature to making a dummy search condition when dealing with a chain of `AND` operations which may contain zero elements.

Comment: Thank you for the hint 
List.OrderBy(c => 1). Did not know about that!

Both your answers helped me to fix my problem. Which one should i mark as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to simplify, you can't remove the decision making from your code, but you could order the sort statements better:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<Client> orderedClients;

case SortType.MostVisits:
  orderedClients = clients.OrderBy(x => x.numberOfVisits);
  if(settingsTellsMeToDoSo)
      orderedClients = orderedClients.ThenBy(x => x.param);
break;
```

then after the switch is ended:

```
clients = orderedClients.ToList();
```

Comment: I was unaware that it was possible to call ThenBy() without a OrderBy directly in front of it, since I always called .ToList() after the first ordering... But without that, your way should work!

Comment: What i meant by simplifying is to split that ordering into two seperate parts in order to avoid a few if-clauses...

Thank you for helping! your answer helped!

Comment: Glad it helped. Looking more closely I do think you need an intermediate variable to hold the result from `OrderBy`.

Comment: yes that is true. I used a IEnumerable variable to store the filtered (.Where()) and then "converted" that into an IOrderedEnumerable with var.OrderBy(x => 1), and then applied my second sort-parameter. 
But thank you!